# How to validate API response against multiple instance of data base from feature file in Karate API automation?

Tags: automation, karate

> I have developed a script which executes against one DB instance e.g.: db1. The code to connect to DB is written in Background section. Now what i want to do is, i have to execute same test script against diffrent db instance e.g.:db2

```
Feature:Execution against multiple DB instance.
##############################################
Background:
* def db_properties = {db_username,db_password,db_connection_string,driver}
* def createConnection = path to read .java file
* def readFromDB = new createConnection(db_properties)
##############################################
```

In  * def db_properties, i have hard coded the actual values of username, password, conenction string and driver.**What exactly i want to do is, i have to validate my API response agains't another DB instance e.g. build is deployed in another environment, and db properties which i have mentioned is diffrent environment**. How can i do it?

Comment: @Peterthomas I have marked previous answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Karate. Maybe the solution is to have 2 sets of DB connection values in your `karate-config.js`. Please figure out a solution that is appropriate for your situation.